# Como fazer um each no DataTable e pegar somente as linhas selecionadas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable, javascript-eventos

Bom dia,

Estou precisando "VARRER" meu Datatable e pegar somente a linha selecionada, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

A ação irá ocorrer após o click de um botão qualquer.

Tenho esse código abaixo onde eu consigo varrer o DataTable e pegar o valor do obj da coluna que preciso jogar num array, mas preciso somente dos valores onde tenho marcado as linhas e não todas, dessa maneira ele está pegando todas as linhas:

```
$('#btnAceitar').on('click', function(event) {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja dar aceite de saída de NF?')) {
    $('#tabela_listaFuncVeic').DataTable().columns(3).every(function() {
        data = this.data();   

        //FAZ O LOOP PARA ADD NA VARIAVEL DO TIPO ARRAY
        $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
            console.log(idx);

            vObj += (obj + '||');
        });
    });
} else {
    return false;              
};                 
});
```

A tela é conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linhas selecionadas ganham a classe `.selected`. Então basta você percorrer todas as linhas da tabela e pegar apenas as que possuem essa classe e adicionar o valor na array `vObj[]`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabela_listaFuncVeic').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        }
    } );
} );


$('#btnAceitar').on('click', function(event) {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja dar aceite de saída de NF?')) {
    $('#tabela_listaFuncVeic').DataTable().columns(3).every(function() {
       
       vObj = []; // cria a array
       var linhas = this.rows()[0]; // pega todas as linhas
       var $this = this; // atribui a tabela a uma variável

        //FAZ O LOOP PARA ADD NA VARIAVEL DO TIPO ARRAY
        $.each(linhas, function(idx, obj) {
           
           // pega cada linha
           var linha = $this.row(obj).nodes().to$()[0];
            // verifica se a linha tem a classe .selected
            if( $(linha).hasClass("selected") ){
               vObj.push($this.data()[obj]); // coloca o valor da coluna na array
            }

        });
        
        console.log(vObj);
    });
} else {
    return false;              
};                 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabela_listaFuncVeic" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <button id="btnAceitar">Aceitar</button>
```

Comment: Sam deu certo consegui somente pegar a linha selecionada, porém com a troca dessa linha $.each(dados, function(idx, obj) { para $.each(linhas, function(idx, obj) { como faço agora para poder pegar o valor da columns(3) e montar meu array?

Comment: Esqueci desse detalhe. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Perfeito Sam, funcionou, muito obrigado.